# How do I prevent one UIView from being hidden by another UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm creating a custom, reusable segmented controller using `UIViews` and I'm having a problem with overlapping views. It currently looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the blue selector is *under* the buttons but I want it to sit *at* the bottom and be four pixels high. To do this, I have:

```
let numberOfButtons = CGFloat(buttonTitles.count)
let selectorWidth = frame.width / numberOfButtons
let selectorYPosition = frame.height - 3 <--- This cause it to be hidden behind the button
selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: selectorYPosition, width: selectorWidth, height: 4))
selector.layer.cornerRadius = 0
selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
addSubview(selector)
bringSubviewToFront(selector) <--- I thought this would work but it does nothing
```

which results in the selector `UIView` being hidden behind the segment `UIView` (I have the Y position set to - 3 so you can see how it's being covered up. I actually want it to be - 4, but that makes it disappear entirely):

[image]

I thought using `bringSubviewToFront()` would bring it in front of the segment `UIView` but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've looked through Apple View Programming Guide and lots of SO threads but can't find an answer.

Can anybody help me see what I'm missing?

**Full code**:

```
class CustomSegmentedControl: UIControl {
  var buttons = [UIButton]()
  var selector: UIView!
  var selectedButtonIndex = 0

  var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
      layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
  }

  var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
    didSet {
      layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
  }

  var separatorBorderColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {
    didSet {

    }
  }

  var commaSeparatedTitles: String = "" {
    didSet {
      updateView()
    }
  }

  var textColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
    didSet {
      updateView()
    }
  }

  var selectorColor: UIColor = .blue {
    didSet {
      updateView()
    }
  }

  var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .black {
    didSet {
      updateView()
    }
  }

  func updateView() {
    buttons.removeAll()
    subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

    // create buttons
    let buttonTitles = commaSeparatedTitles.components(separatedBy: ",")
    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles {
      let button = UIButton(type: .system)
      button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
      button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
      buttons.append(button)
    }

    // make first button selected
    buttons[0].setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)

    let numberOfButtons = CGFloat(buttonTitles.count)
    let selectorWidth = frame.width / numberOfButtons
    let selectorYPosition = frame.height - 3
    selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: selectorYPosition, width: selectorWidth, height: 4))
    selector.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
    addSubview(selector)
    bringSubviewToFront(selector)

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  @objc func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
      btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)

      if btn == button {
        let numberOfButtons = CGFloat(buttons.count)
        let selectorStartPosition = frame.width / numberOfButtons * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { self.selector.frame.origin.x = selectorStartPosition })
        btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
      }
    }

    sendActions(for: .valueChanged)

  }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you do `stackView.bringSubviewToFront(selector)`?

Comment: I just added `stackView.bringSubviewToFront(selector)` and it had no effect. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are covering up your `selector` with the stackView.

You need to do:

```
bringSubviewToFront(selector)
```

after you have added all of the views.  Move that line to the bottom of `updateView()`.